# Where f is differentiable?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

> In the following function, describe the set of points (x,y) where f is differentiable: $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}{x^2},& (x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\\ 0,& (x,y)\notin \mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}.\end{cases}$$
>
> With the limit

Comment: It seems that you could easily simplify the definition and make the question rather easy.

Comment: $$\frac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{{x^2+y^2}}=xy$$ where $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$.

Comment: Which definitions are you familiar with? Is the function continuous at $(0,0)$, for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First $$\frac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$ is differentiable everywhere but $(x,y) = (0,0)$ because it is a fraction and multiplication of differentiable functions ($x$ and $y$ are differentiable). Now $f(x)$ is differentiable in $(x,y)=(0,0)$ if the following is true, the limit must exist and must be equal to $0$: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = 0 $$

It is very easy to see that:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} xy = 0$$ So $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere.